# How can I test a function that use a promise?

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, angular-test, jasmine-node, angular-testing-library

how can I test a function that call a promise ?

```
click() {
    this.todoService.getUsers().then(
      (resp) => {
        this.users = resp;
      },
      (reject) => {
        console.log(reject);
      }
    );
  }
```

I tried this , but the console return undeefined

```
  it('should get all users', () => {
  const users =[....]
    todoServiceSpy.getUsers.and.returnValue(of(users).toPromise());
    component.click();
    console.log('component.users', component.users);

    expect(component.users).toEqual(users);
```

I'm new in testings

Answer (score 1):

You can use `async/fixture.whenStable()` to wait for the promises in queue to complete before proceeding.

```
// add async here
it('should get all users', async () => {
    const users =[....]
    todoServiceSpy.getUsers.and.returnValue(of(users).toPromise());
    component.click();
    
    // !! wait for all promises in queue to complete before proceeding
    await fixture.whenStable();
    console.log('component.users', component.users);
    // do assertions
    expect(component.users).toEqual(users);
```

You can also use `fakeAsync/tick`. I suggest you read up on these methodologies.

It explains some of it here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-testing-async-fakeasync.

Comment: Hi. thanks,I'm see that exist a lot way to test. also work using async with flushMicrotasks() or tick

Comment: Yes, many ways to do the same thing.